# Latest ATL version

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I couldn't find the exact number of current Active Template Library (ATL) which distribute along with Visual Studio 2012. Does anyone have an idea about the exact version number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `atldef.h`:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Master version numbers

#define _ATL     1      // Active Template Library
#define _ATL_VER 0x0A00 // Active Template Library version 10.00

#ifndef _ATL_FILENAME_VER
#define _ATL_FILENAME_VER "100"
#endif

#ifndef _ATL_FILENAME_VER_NUM
#define _ATL_FILENAME_VER_NUM 100
#endif

#ifndef _ATL_VER_RBLD
#define _ATL_VER_RBLD "10.00"
#endif
```